# How to pass value for a treeset in spring?

Tags: java, spring

How to Set the argument value for a TreeSet in Spring?

```
public class Trainer {
    String name;
    TreeSet<String> batches;
    public Trainer(String name, TreeSet<String> batches) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.batches = batches;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder x=new StringBuilder();
        x.append("trainer:").append(name).append("\n");
        x.append("batches:\n");
        for(String a :batches)
        {
            x.append(a).append("\n");

        }
        return x.toString();
    }
}
```

//here is the configuration file

```
<beans>
            <bean id="abc" class="Trainer">
            <constructor-arg value="asfsad"/>
            <constructor-arg>
            <set>
            <value>kasdaskdnas</value>
            <value>sjbdlsas;dkas</value>            
            </set>
        </constructor-arg>
        </bean>
        </beans>
```

This throws an exception when trying to Create a object for it,could not convert constructor argument value of type [java.util.LinkedHashSet] to required type [java.util.TreeSet]:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `util:set` tag

```
<beans>
    <bean id="abc" class="Trainer">
        <constructor-arg value="asfsad" />
        <constructor-arg>
            <util:set set-class="java.util.TreeSet">
                <value>kasdaskdnas</value>
                <value>sjbdlsas;dkas</value>
            </util:set>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: What does this util tag actually does?

Comment: allows you to specify the set class

Comment: The prefix "util" for element "util:list" is not bound. it throws this exception

Comment: remember to include the `util` namespace declaration to the `beans` tag definition in the application context file - [example](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-setfactorybean-example/)

Answer (score 0):

You can control the implementation of `Set` to be used for your Sring-managed set using the `set-class` attribute.

Something like this: `<set set-class="java.util.TreeSet">`